# SCOPE_IDENTITY And Instead of Insert Trigger work-around

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

OK, I have a table with no natural key, only an integer identity column as it's primary key. I'd like to insert and retrieve the identity value, but also use a trigger to ensure that certain fields are always set. Originally, the design was to use instead of insert triggers, but that breaks scope_identity. The output clause on the insert statement is also broken by the instead of insert trigger. So, I've come up with an alternate plan and would like to know if there is anything obviously wrong with what I intend to do:

begin contrived example:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData] (
    [TestId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NOT NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDataModInfo](
    [TestId] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [RowCreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL)

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDataModInfo]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT
    [FK_TestDataModInfo_TestData] FOREIGN KEY([TestId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[TestData] ([TestId]) ON DELETE CASCADE

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestData$AfterInsert]
   ON [dbo].[TestData]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestDataModInfo]
           ([TestId],
            [RowCreateDate])
        SELECT
            [TestId],
            current_timestamp
        FROM inserted

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
```

End contrived example.

No, I'm not doing this for one little date field - it's just an example.

The fields that I want to ensure are set have been moved to a separate table (in TestDataModInfo) and the trigger ensures that it's updated. This works, it allows me to use scope_identity() after inserts, and appears to be safe (if my after trigger fails, my insert fails). Is this bad design, and if so, why?

Comment: Thanks Joel - didn't see my own sloppy typing.

Comment: I assume you are validating fields in triggers rather than constraints because of legacy data?

Comment: @Maslow, the triggers should be the simplest, strongest way to ensure that certain fields are always or never updated (updateDate, createdate). These ensure that you can't break those rules unless you also have permission to disable the triggers. Just one more layer of protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, SCOPE_IDENTITY is designed for this situation. It's not affected by AFTER trigger code, unlike @@IDENTITY.

Apart from using stored procs, this is OK.

I use AFTER triggers for auditing because they are convenient... that is, write to another table in my trigger.

Edit: [SCOPE_IDENTITY and parallelism in SQL Server 2005 cam have a problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811)

Comment: You can't really say that scope_identity isn't affected by trigger code - it returns null if you use an 'instead of insert' trigger.

Comment: @Peter, true, was typing too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried using OUTPUT to get the value back instead?

Comment: Output also returns null when using instead of insert triggers.

Comment: well then I guess you really have no other choice but to use an after trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
SELECT scope_identity();
```

http://wiki.alphasoftware.com/Scope_Identity+in+SQL+Server+with+nested+and+INSTEAD+OF+triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INSTEAD OF trigger just fine, by in the trigger capturing the value just after the insert to the main table, then spoofing the `Scope_Identity()` into `@@Identity` at the end of the trigger:

```
-- Inside of trigger
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT dbo.YourTable VALUES(blah, blah, blah);
SET @YourTableID = Scope_Identity();

-- ... other DML that inserts to another identity-bearing table

-- Last statement in trigger
SELECT YourTableID INTO #Trash FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE YourTableID = @YourTableID;
```

Or, here's an alternate final statement that doesn't use any reads, but may cause permission issues if the executing user doesn't have rights (though there are solutions to this).

```
SET @SQL =
   'SELECT identity(smallint, ' + Str(@YourTableID) + ', 1) YourTableID INTO #Trash';
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Note that `Scope_Identity()` may return NULL on a table with an INSTEAD OF trigger on it in some cases, even if you use this spoofing method. But you can at least get the value using `@@Identity`. This can make MS Access ADP projects start working right again after breaking because you put a trigger on a table that the front end inserts to.

Also, be aware that any parallelism at all can make `@@Identity` and `Scope_Identity()` return incorrect values—so use `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` or `TOP 1` or a single-row `VALUES` clause to defeat this problem.