# Inserting many records using sql trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two tables with 1 to many relationship. Here are they:

[image]

When inserting into `ActivityAttribute` I would like to use generated `idAA` for inserting many records to `PersonActivityAttribute` - one for each existing value of PersonActivityAttribute.idPA. It goes like this: when I insert a new record to `ActivityAttribute` with `idAA = 5` I want the following result

[image]

The question is - how can I achive it using trigger? Is it possible?

Comment: So every time a record is inserted into `ActivityAttribute`, you want to insert a new record into `PersonActivityAttribute` for **each** existing value of `PersonActivityAttribute.idPA`? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking and so your question might not be clear enough.

Comment: I believe this is pretty much what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434088/scope-identity-and-instead-of-insert-trigger-work-around.

Comment: @3N1GM4 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the below query

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert on ActivityAttribute
FOR INSERT
AS DECLARE @idAA INT;
SELECT @idAA=i.idAA FROM inserted i;
INSERT INTO PersonActivityAttribute(idPA,idAA,value)
SELECT DISTINCT idPA, @idAA, NULL value
FROM PersonActivityAttribute;
```

Hope this should help you out.